# Copying data from dataframes of different sizes, with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes df1-df2, of different sizes (df2 has more rows and columns than df1).

```html
df1
unit  rate  
aa    nan    
cc    nan 

df2
unit  date  rate  type
aa    1     100   x1
bb    2     150   x2
cc    3     200   x3
dd    4     250   x4
```

I am trying to assign the value from df2['rate'] into df1['rate'], in rows where df1['unit'] == df2['unit'].

The desired output is

```html
df1
unit  rate  
aa    100
cc    200
```

I have tried different ways:

```
df1['rate'] = df2.loc[(df2['unit'].reset_index(drop=True) == df1['unit']), 'rate']
```

gives me ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

```
df1['rate'] = df2.loc[(df2['unit'].reset_index(drop=True).str == df1['unit'].str), 'rate']
```

gives me False

I think this comes from the fact that the two dataframes have different sizes to start with. However i don't understand why it should prevent it from doing the comparison. I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use 'merge':

```
dfm = df1.merge(df2, left_on='unit', right_on='unit')
dfm = dfm.drop(columns=['date','type','rate_x'])
dfm = dfm.rename(columns={"rate_y": "rate"})
print(dfm)


  unit  rate
0   aa   100
1   cc   200
```

Comment: Thank you. I think you meant dfm.drop(columns=['date','type']). I understand there's no easy way to replace, and i have to merge/drop columns (in my case i have quite a few to remove...).

Comment: Oh, yes, you're right. I updated the code since you'll end having two columns named 'rate_x' and 'rate_y' and you'll need one more step to fix that. Hope that works for you.